# RemoveIf generate an exception, why?

Tags: java, lambda, predicate

I try to remove an item from a list using lambda expression but removeIf generate an exception, why?

In this Orlacle video jdk8 8 MOOC  introduce removeif with list and not arraylist.  Is it right ? https://youtu.be/olKF7VpJMfg?list=PLMod1hYiIvSZL1xclvHcsV2dMiminf19x&t=137

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> parole = Arrays.asList("Lambda ", "expressions ", "are ", "cool ");
Predicate <String> findAre= s->"are ".equals(s);         
        parole.removeIf(findAre);
        parole.forEach( System.out::println);
            }
```

[Here pict with code and Exception in thread "main"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbBZ5.png)

Comment: Please post this as a [mcve] and include the exception as *text*. Providing a screenshot has no benefit here, and means the exception type isn't indexed...

Comment: `Arrays.asList` just wraps the array provided. You can't change the length of the array.

Answer (score 7):

`Arrays.asList` produces a fixed sized list backed by an array, so you can't add or remove elements from it.

You can create an `ArrayList` in order to support removal:

```
List<String> parole = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Lambda ", "expressions ", "are ", "cool "));
```

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion, please use iterator during list iteration to remove objects from arraylist instead of for each loop, as you will get Concurrency modifying exception.